# Setting a Spring bean class name using a SpEL expression and PropertyPlaceHolder

Tags: java, spring

**UPDATED: Resolution summary as of 12/9/2016**

According to @altazar's answer below, [this is now possible](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12817) as of Spring 4.2!

**Old resolution summary as of 3/29/2012**

As of this date, Spring SpEL **could not execute** inside a `class` attribute of a `<bean>`.

**Original question:**

I'm trying to implement a dynamic `class` attribute for a Spring bean, ultimately set using a combination of a `PropertyPlaceHolder` property and a SpEL expression. The purpose is to choose either a production or debug version of a class to instantiate.  It is not working and I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve.

So far, I have the following:

**Flat properties file**:

```
is.debug.mode=false
```

**Spring XML config**:

```
<bean id="example"
      class="#{ ${is.debug.mode} ?
                    com.springtest.ExampleDebug :
                    com.springtest.ExampleProd}"
/>
```

**Spring bootstrap Java code**:

```
    // Get basic ApplicationContext - DO NOT REFRESH
    FileSystemXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new
            FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
            (new String[] {pathSpringConfig}, false);

    // Load properties
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader ();
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("file:" + pathProperties);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(resource.getInputStream());

    // Link to ApplicationContext
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer =
            new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer()   ;
    propertyConfigurer.setProperties(properties) ;
    applicationContext.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(propertyConfigurer);

    // Refresh - load beans
    applicationContext.refresh();

    // Done
    Example example = (Example) applicationContext.getBean("example");
```

**Error message (with a lot of whitespace removed for clarity)**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
 #{ true ? com.springtest.ExampleDebug : com.springtest.ExampleProd}
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  . . .
```

As you can see by the "`true`" in the message, the `is.debug.mode` property is successfully loaded and substituted.  But something else is going wrong.  Is it my bootstrap sequence in the Java?  Or the SPeL syntax in the XML?  Or a different issue?

BTW I am aware of the new 3.1 profiles feature, but I would like to do this via SPeL for a variety of reasons.  Also I realize I'm using a filesystem-based context and paths - I have reasons for that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could accomplish what you intend with a factoryBean:

```
<bean id="example" class="MyFactoryBean">
  <property name="class" value="#{ ${is.debug.mode} ? com.springtest.ExampleDebug : com.springtest.ExampleProd}"/>
</bean>
```

where MyFactoryBean is a trivial FactoryBean implementation returning instance of indicated class.

Comment: +1 This is another good workaround.  Are you saying basically that SPeL evaluation just does not happen in the `class` attribute of a `<bean>`?

Comment: I think class is not processed through EL. I vaguely remember checking this in sources.

Comment: I trust your memory of checking the source.  I just got the very same SPeL expression to work in a `<property value=>`, while still failing in a `<bean class=>`.  That to me is confirmation and I am going with yours as the answer.

Comment: By the way, I am using the 3.1 profiles feature as the workaround - definitely worth checking out, see [this article](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/).

Comment: Thanks, we're using 3.0 at the moment, will try to migrate when I find some time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.

```
debug.class=com.springtest.ExampleDebug
#debug.class=com.springtest.ExampleProd
```

and then

```
<bean id="example" class="${debug.class}"/>
```

Comment: This is a good workaround and I may resort to it.  But are you certain SpEL doesn't work in spring context XML?  [This Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based) seems to show that it does.  Or did you mean the type of `ApplicationContext` that I'm currently using?  Thanks.

Comment: You have right it should work. What kind of application do you have? Did you try expression like this #{ properties['is.debug.mode'] ? .. : ..}

Comment: Maybe attribute class doesn't support SpEL evaluation. Try put expression to some property.

Comment: Tried the syntax you suggested, it couldn't resolve `properties['is.debug.mode']`.  At any rate we know it was resolving `${is.debug.mode}` because the error message from the original post shows it resolving to `true`.  Re whether `class` supports SpEL evaluation, I've done a fair amount of Googling and have seen some people suggest that it does, but no real working examples.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get ClassNotFoundExcpetion statign that class "${debug.class}" was not found. Hence it seems this is not resolved within the class attribute.

Answer (score 2):

From Spring 4.2 it [is possible](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12817) to use SpEl in class attribute so following works well:

```
<bean id="example" 
      class="#{T(java.lang.Boolean).parseBoolean('${is.debug.mode:false}') ?       
              'com.springtest.ExampleDebug' :                              
              'com.springtest.ExampleProd'}"/>
```

In my case placeholder `${is.debug.mode:false}` was not work, so I parse it explicitly.